# The pipe 'async' could not be found

Tags: asynchronous, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular2-observables

I am trying to build a simple blog with Angular 2 and Firebase and I am having issues using async pipe in a component. I get the error in the console.

> zone.js:344Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
> The pipe 'async' could not be found ("
>
> [ERROR ->]{{ (blog.user | async)?.first_name }}
>
> "): BlogComponent@6:3 ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Template parse errors:(…) Error: Template parse errors:
> The pipe 'async' could not be found ("

blog.component.ts

```ts
import {Component, Input} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: 'blog-component',
  templateUrl: './blog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./blog.component.css'],
})

export class BlogComponent {
  @Input() blog;
}
```

blog.component.html

```html
<h1 class="article-title">{{ blog.title }}</h1>
<p>{{ (blog.user | async)?.first_name }}</p>
```

app.component.ts

```ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BlogService } from "./services/services.module";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private blogService: BlogService) {}
  articles = this.blogService.getAllArticles();
}
```

app.component.html

```html
<article *ngFor="let article of articles | async">
  <blog-component [blog]="article"></blog-component>
</article>
```

blog.service.ts

```ts
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {AngularFire} from "angularfire2";
import {Observable} from "rxjs";
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";

@Injectable()
export class BlogService {
  constructor(private af: AngularFire) { }

  getAllArticles(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.af.database.list('articles', {
      query: {
        orderByKey: true,
        limitToLast: 10
      }
    }).map((articles) => {
      return articles.map((article) => {
        article.user = this.af.database.object(`/users/${article.user_id}`);
        return article;
      });
    });
  }
}
```

The problem arises only when I try to use async in blog.component.html file. It works if I try to print the user name in app.component.html file. Should I be injecting AsyncPipe in blog.module.ts? How can I get the async working in blog.component.ts?

Comment: Try adding `CommonModule` to your `BlogModule`'s `imports`

Comment: Awesome, Thanks much! That worked. Reply as answer and I'll mark as right answer.

Comment: thanks it worked :)

Comment: I was missing the component in the child module's declarations, that's why I was getting the error. If that helps someone.

Answer (score 246, accepted):

`@NgModule.declarations` aren't inherited by child modules. If you need pipes, directives, components from a module, the module should be imported into your feature module.

The module with all the core pipes is `CommonModule` from `@angular/common`

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ CommonModule ]
})
class BlogModule {}
```

The reason it works in the `app.component` is because you are most likely importing `BrowserModule` into the `AppModule`. `BrowserModule` re-exports `CommonModule`, so by importing `BrowserModule`, it's like also importing `CommonModule`.

It's also worth noting that `CommonModule` has the core directives also, like `ngFor` and `ngIf`. So if you have a feature module that uses those, you will also need to import the `CommonModule` into that module.

Comment: This answer also fixed my situation where I was using the `date` pipe in a component that is declared/exported in a shared module. Thanks.

Comment: In addition to that, reordering `@NgModule.imports` array declarations solved my issue; hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 75):

If the component at the route you're loading is not declared (via `declarations:[]`) then you will also get this type of error.

Comment: Or a subtle variation of this answer: forgetting to declare the component under test in your `TestBed.configureTestingModule` call. 

Comment: Thank you. Everyone keeps talking about "You just have to import CommonModule" and nobody ever tells that this is also one of the reasons.

Comment: Thanks @Jeroen I spent over an hour figuring out why I got this error even though I had imported CommonModule

Comment: @StephaneJanicaud Yeah programming is fun, except when it's not 

Comment: @Jeroen Yes, another thank you for the article you wrote about OAuth2 + OIDC and SPA, I think it'll also help me a lot with silent refresh issues I may encounter as I use the same library :)

Comment: Or another subtle variation, when you add to the declarations for 1 module (for example using `ng g c my-component`), then move the component to another module and forget to move the declaration across

Comment: Either this or you did not define your route yet. Happened to me when I restructured my app and put a component into a new module with its own routing.

Answer (score 22):

When adding a new component in Angular 9 I had to restart the development server possibly also because of HMR:

```
ng serve --hmr
```

Without this the application simply did not load all the dependencies and issued this error.

Comment: This can also happen if you rearrange dependent services. For example I had a `SavingsService` that I split into `SavingsService` and `SavingsUIService`. After recompiling I got the real error, which was that the new service wasn't being provided anywhere. So yes this can definitely be a red herring requiring full recompilation

Comment: @MikeGledhill I think this is related to the optimizations being performed when using HMR, to prevent reloading of the whole component tree. Most likely the package containing the async pipe is not injected for the new component.

Answer (score 19):

Component you're trying to load is not declared in the declarations array then you will get this type of error, in my case this was shipping component, like mentioned below:

[image]

Comment: This answer would be better if the image was text instead of an image of text, or even if the text associated with the image was something other than "enter image description here"...

Answer (score 16):

If you tried all above mentioned answers but it is not working means , Just do `npm run start` it will work , 
In my case after some compilation issue this error came.

Comment: so wierd - but it help me to . probably it restart the angular server in a better way ?

Comment: Yes sometimes during a large refactor, this is the only solution...

Answer (score 10):

If you have upgraded to Angular 6 or 7, make sure in your **tsconfig.ts** turn off enableIvy in 
**angularCompilerOptions**

e.g:

```
angularCompilerOptions: {
enableIvy : false; // default is true
}
```

That solved my issue, may be it'll save someone else time too.

Comment: This does work, but I hope to see a real fix besides disabling core system functionality.

Comment: I was reading somewhere to import `CommonModule` globally can solve this issue too but I haven't tested yet.

Comment: Ivy is not production ready yet, so skip it for angular 7, enable for angular 8 onwards

Comment: Once they have Ivy ready for production, there might be other workaround for async pipe, I know people have already raised bug for this issue.

Comment: This solved my issue. Using Angular 7.2.4 and the async pipe extensively throughout the app, but sadly compiling for production fails with `The pipe 'async' could not be found.`. Disabling Ivy worked.

Comment: Not the right answer. Disabling Ivy is a workaround.

Comment: As of Angular 9 I still see this issue. This answer is old and irrelevant now that Ivy is live.

Comment: This is a bandaid masking an underlying issue. It will get rid of the error and not the problem the error is about.

Answer (score 7):

I found the same problem some times when changing multiple imports at once.

My app worked back again just fine without changing any code but restarting `ng start`. One of the surprises of coding until late.

Normally this drives me crazy as I was checking all the imports, and the answer of the "Common Module" normally makes sense, but just in case someone finds the same silly situation I faced, now you know what to do.

Comment: This was the case for me. I had made a change to a module and had to stop and restart the app. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

In my case the input to the pipe was null.
So in the case of the question make sure that `blog.user` in `<p>{{ (blog.user | async)?.first_name }}</p>` is not null.

Answer (score 4):

If like me you're developing a standalone component,

I was missing

```
import { AsyncPipe } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
   selector: 'test',
   standalone: true,
   imports: [
      AsyncPipe
   ],
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss']
})
```

Answer (score 3):

**edit**: I have been doing my own project, and I have noticed that this error might occur when code has *any* kind of build error, for example unclosed html tag like `<label>foo<label>`. After that, the only way I know, is to just reset the entire server. It is annoying and shouldn't be like that.

---

I got this error when I had an empty (actually commented) function implementation in my component

in html:
`<div (click)="onClickFoo()">`

in .ts

```
onClickFoo() {
     // this.router.navigate([...])
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Basic reason:

The pipe `async` is exported from the `CommonModule` and you will get this error when you forgot to import `CommonModule` either in the module importing your component or in the component itself (if you are in [standalone](https://angular.io/guide/standalone-components) mode.

Advanced one:

Now you might also get the "pipe async not found" if angular, for some reason, has not been able to preload properly the `CommonModule`.

To check if this is the case, you can force Angular preloading all the modules, changing your code as follows:

```js
// Probably in app-routing.module.ts

import { RouterModule, PreloadAllModules } from '@angular/router';

RouterModule.forRoot([
], {
  // Add this property to your main router module
  preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules
})
```

Then reload the page, if the problem is gone, it very likely means angular is not able to resolve your routes dependencies properly. You could for instance have a module importing its routes but also importing another module itself importing its routes.

Answer (score 1):

You can also get the same error if you are using multiple modules in your app.module.ts

```
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

// module 1
@NgModule({ exports: [MatCardModule] })
export class MaterialModule {}

// module 2
@NgModule({
    imports: [MaterialModule]
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Then if you generate a component using the command:

```
ng generate component example
```

It gets added to the first module, instead of the second one:

```
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ExampleComponent } from './example/example.component';

// module 1
@NgModule({ exports: [MatCardModule], declarations: [ExampleComponent] })
export class MaterialModule {}

// module 2
@NgModule({
    imports: [MaterialModule]
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Which will create the same error! Moving the component to the AppModule will fix it.

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [MaterialModule]
    declarations: [AppComponent, ExampleComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting this in an optimized production build it could be due to tree shaking, especially if you're using `sideEffects: false`. This is now an encouraged setting in Angular 10 via `ng new --strict`.

[Still have yet to figure out how to fix my project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62617305/tree-shaking-for-angular-10-shook-out-asyncpipe-when-using-sideeffects-false), but setting it to true fixed it for me for now.

Answer (score 1):

Previous answers are good (remember to do `declarations:[]`), but also remember to **restart your watch** (only if you're using CMD `npm-run webpack-development -- -- progress --watch`.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue when I tried to use the async pipe in a component used as a dialog. I solved this by declaring the component in the immediate module (I used lazy loading). The app module if you are not.

Answer (score 0):

Also, make sure that you're importing the module that the component is declared in.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the name of a component could also cause this error, and you can solve this by manually checking the imports in the app module, because it will probably be messed up.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a STANDALONE component, add "CommonModule" to the imports[CommonModule] @Component metadata.

e.g.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'a-standalone-component',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],

  template: `testMsg$ {{testMsg$ | async}}
```