# How to fix "ERROR in : Template parse errors: The pipe 'async' could not be found" after Angular 7 upgrade on production build

Tags: angular, module, pipe, upgrade, angular7

I have recently upgraded from Angular 4 to Angular 7 and got into some issues on production build when running `ng build --prod`. The error I put in the title is from the node_module dependency. However, I had around 15 pipe filters that I commented throughout the code to make sure I didn't do anything wrong in terms of module importing and dependencies, which now hits the node_module dependency and break the build with the same error.

For instance if I un-comment one of my filters in my code

```
    <td>{{ item.registeredDate | date }}</td>
```

I get the following error:

```
    ERROR in : Template parse errors:
    The pipe 'date' could not be found ("<td>{{[ERROR ->]item.registeredDate | date }}</td>")
```

I can provide more details.

Thanks,

Comment: Looks like you need to disable ivy in your `tsconfig`: [GitHub issue](https://github.com/akveo/nebular/issues/1122#issuecomment-451499779), [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53120833/4362829).

Comment: I did that I get the following errors:

```
ERROR in : Error: Internal error: unknown identifier undefined
    at Object.importExpr$$1 [as importExpr] (path_to_my_project/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:24166:27)

```

Comment: Did you follow the steps mentioned in https://update.angular.io/  while upgrading?

Answer (score -1):

I guess you try to upgrade to angular 7 directly. You can not immigrate to angular 7, from 4. 
You should upgrade to angular 5, and build a prod, (ng build --prod; ng serve) then from angular 5 to 6 and then finally to 7.